# How to assert that a API response has a specific structure?

Tags: c#, api, response, specflow

I have a SpecFlow test definition set up where I want to assert that the response have a specific collection of fields in its response. For example I have this particular expected response from the API:

```
{
    isActive: false,
    lastProcessed: "2020-11-03T19:03:16.537"

}
```

What I want to verify is that the response contains those two fields, not necessarily the value those fields contain. I tried the following method:

```
Assert.NotNull(response.Model.isActive);
Assert.NotNull(response.Model.lastProcessed);
```

But I'm getting an error using this method:
`Do not use Assert.NotNull() on value type 'bool'`

How else can I make sure the response structure is as expected other than using "NotNull()"?

**The Solution**:
Following the accepted answer, I serialized the model returned from the API call into JSON and parsed it into a JObject. Then I used the ContainsKey() method to assert it.

```
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response.Model));
Assert.True(jObject.ContainsKey("isActive"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what packages you use for sending requests and deserialization but if you could get the response content as a raw json string you could then use Newtonsoft.JSON to parse the response into a `JObject` with `JObject.Parse(responseContent)`. `JObject` has a method called `ContainsKey(propertyName)` which determines whether there is a field of a specified name in the object. You could assert if it returns true for the desired property names.

**Edit**

Regarding Greg's answer below. The original error is in fact caused by `bool` not being a nullable type and making it nullable in the model would fix the error. However, this solution is not ideal. In some cases `null` can be a valid value returned by the API and this would generate false negatives. e.g. if we recieved:

```
{
    isActive: null,
    lastProcessed: "2020-11-03T19:03:16.537"
}
```

then `Assert.NotNull(response.Model.isActive)` would yield a negative test result even though the field is present in the json, and that's what we wanted to check.

So theoretically if we are 100% sure that `null` will never be returned by the API itself, then we could do it that way, but it won't be a universal method. Also not very descriptive of what we are trying to achieve ;)

Comment: I do use NewtonSoft.JSON for serialization and deserialization. Will try this, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since the `isActive` property is a `bool` you'll need to assert that it is false. If instead you want a true or false value, and then something to represent that it is missing, use a nullable boolean instead in your DTO:

```
public class YourDTO
{
    public bool? isActive { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Then you can assert `isActive` is null, true or false.

---

**Alternative:** If you cannot update the original data transfer object, then this might be a good use case for writing your own code to call the web service and map the JSON response to your own DTO used just for your tests.

This could be a large amount of work, however. The advantage is your test code is truly decoupled from the code it tests. I've done this with applications that use a database as well. It is extra work, but it allows your tests to use whatever data structure makes sense for the test.

Comment: there's an API contract in place, so I can't change that specific field into a nullable. If that field isn't set, is "false" a default value that is placed?

Comment: `false` is the default value for the bool datatype. Without the ability to change the DTO, or use our own DTO, then all you can do is assert `isActive` is false.